# Simplify Javascript Object functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, methods

I have the following javascript object:

```
Quotes = {
    quote: '#home-quotes .quote',
    quoteWrap: '#home-quotes .quote-wrap',
    leftTrigger: '#home-quotes .quote-left',
    rightTrigger: '#home-quotes .quote-right',
    sliderDot: '#home-quotes .slider-dots li',
    init: function() {
        $(this.rightTrigger).click(this.quoteRight.bind(this));
        $(this.leftTrigger).click(this.quoteLeft.bind(this));
        $(this.sliderDot).click(this.sliderDots.bind(this));
    },
    quoteRight: function(e) {
        var firstQuote = $(this.quote).first(),
            lastQuote = $(this.quote).last(),
            activeQuote = $('.quote.active'),
            nextUp = activeQuote.next();
            quoteWidth = $(this.quote).width();
            moveLeft = -(quoteWidth*2);
        // replaceLeft = -(quoteWidth);
        if ( $(window).width() > 977 ) {
            var updateLeft = '-978px';
        } else {
            var updateLeft = '-100vw';
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this.quoteWrap).removeClass('no-transition');
        $(this.quoteWrap).css('left', moveLeft);
        setTimeout(function(){
            firstQuote.clone().insertAfter(lastQuote);
            firstQuote.remove();
            $('.quote-wrap').addClass('no-transition');
            $('#home-quotes .quote-wrap').css('left', updateLeft);
        }, 500)
        activeQuote.removeClass('active');
        nextUp.addClass('active');
    },
    quoteLeft: function(e) {
        var firstQuote = $(this.quote).first(),
            lastQuote = $(this.quote).last(),
            activeQuote = $('.quote.active'),
            nextUp = activeQuote.prev();
            quoteWidth = $(this.quote).width();
            moveRight = 0;
        if ( $(window).width() > 977 ) {
            var updateLeft = '-978px';
        } else {
            var updateLeft = '-100vw';
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this.quoteWrap).removeClass('no-transition');
        $(this.quoteWrap).css('left', moveRight);
        setTimeout(function(){
            lastQuote.clone().insertBefore(firstQuote);
            lastQuote.remove();
            $('.quote-wrap').addClass('no-transition');
            $('#home-quotes .quote-wrap').css('left', updateLeft);
        }, 500)
        activeQuote.removeClass('active');
        nextUp.addClass('active');
    },
}
```

I am wanting to simplify the 'quoteRight' and 'quoteLeft' functions into one 'moveQuote' function with parameters for the two functions' differences.  I have tried creating a single function, such as:

```
moveQuote: function(direction, distance, sequence) {
    var firstQuote = $(this.quote).first(),
        lastQuote = $(this.quote).last(),
        activeQuote = $('.quote.active'),
        nextUp = activeQuote.sequence();
        quoteWidth = $(this.quote).width();
        movedistance = -(distance*2);
    if ( $(window).width() > 977 ) {
        var updateLeft = -(distance);
    } else {
        var updateLeft = '-100vw';
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this.quoteWrap).removeClass('no-transition');
    $(this.quoteWrap).css(direction, moveLeft);
    setTimeout(function(){
        firstQuote.clone().insertAfter(lastQuote);
        firstQuote.remove();
        $('.quote-wrap').addClass('no-transition');
        $('#home-quotes .quote-wrap').css('left', updateLeft);
    }, 500)
    activeQuote.removeClass('active');
    nextUp.addClass('active');
}
```

and then in my 'init' function, passing the parameters like:

```
$(this.rightTrigger).click(this.moveQuote('Right', '978px', 'next'));
```

My first major issue is that my 'init' 'click' function is running onLoad and not when the 'rightTrigger' is clicked.  Why is this?

Secondly, I can't figure out how to pass parameters as jQuery methods.  For example, the third parameter from the example above ('next') should be passed into the jQuery function 'activeQuote.next()' but I cannot pass the parameter as 'activeQuote.sequence()' as the console returns 'activeQuote.sequence is not a function'.  How can I pass a parameter string as a jQuery method?

Any help with this is much appreciated.  I am just moving into object-oriented javascript and am hoping to get some pointers on the things that I  am doing wrong.

Comment: Return a closure.

Comment: You're looking for `activeQuote[sequence]()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem, you're passing the result of the execution of `moveQuote` into the call to `.click`. You need to pass a callable (function) instead:

```
var this_ref = this;
$(this.rightTrigger).click(function () {
    this_ref.moveQuote('Right', '978px', 'next');
});
```

For the other problem, you need to use square bracket notation to reference a property/method with dynamic data:

```
nextUp = activeQuote[sequence](); //sanity checking for existence is up to you
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that response was extremely helpful and exactly what I was looking for!  Could you help me out with the 'e.preventDefault()' piece.  Now that I am passing paramerters, how can I also pass in the 'e' as I was in the original functions.

Comment: No problem! IMO, `preventDefault` is the job of the immediate handler. As such, the function wrapper I put on your code should take the event param in, and prevent default if that's what you desire. `$(this.rightTrigger).click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); this_ref.moveQuote('Right', '978px', 'next');});` It's not really `moveQuote`'s job to be dealing with that, so I'd remove it from there.

Comment: Yep, completely agree.  Your response has cleared up a lot for me and I thank you for that.  One note...I had to remove the parenthesis after activeQuote[sequence] as the console was returning 'activeQuote.sequence is not a function'.  Is this because adding the brackets to my sequence parameter automatically makes it a function.  A little unclear why removing the parentheses made that work.

Comment: No, removing the parens means you're not calling the function. I'm not sure why it says it's not defined if you're really passing `'next'` as the value of `sequence`

Comment: Correct, I figured that out.  Last question...what is the proper way to pass one of my parameters into a variable name.  For example, my variable 'moveleft' (or 'moveright') should be created from the first parameter.  How do I pass that in?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what you call the variable...as ling as the right value gets set...